# Google Maps KML not show the points

Tags: google-maps, kml

I have a KMZ that contains area polygons and city points also (12 google pins), but they don't appear on the map despite of switched on as u see. How can to visible them? Can anyone help me?

Here is the map: http://goo.gl/maps/Nbrfq

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `<Style>` is not being exported correctly by My Places (or the Google Maps KML parser is not handling it), all your markers have empty styles:

```
<Style id="style2">
</Style>
```

A workaround might be to specify an icon for the marker.

Another work around would be to use [geoxml3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/), the markers show using [geoxml3 and a proxy](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?lat=47.180461&lng=19.506329&zoom=7&type=m&filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/xmlProxy060215.asp?https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?authuser%3D0%26vps%3D5%26ie%3DUTF8%26hl%3Den%26oe%3DUTF8%26msa%3D0%26output%3Dkml%26msid%3D207719308852398276835.0004e7aadbef23d9a5c87) (you can compare to KmlLayer by hiding the markers, then clicking the "show KmlLayer" button).

[Documentation on `<Style>`](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#style).
The styles of your marker objects from the file:

```
  <Style id="style2">
  </Style>
  <Style id="style13">
  </Style>
  <Style id="style7">
  </Style>
  <Style id="style19">
  </Style>
  <Style id="style21">
  </Style>
  <Style id="style24">
  </Style>
  <Style id="style1">
  </Style>
  <Style id="style12">
  </Style>
  <Style id="style8">
  </Style>
  <Style id="style10">
  </Style>
  <Style id="style23">
  </Style>
  <Style id="style22">
  </Style>
  <Style id="style4">
  </Style>
```

Comment: Thank U! But I don't really understand what u mean with style2 id. Here is one point source code. Is the style wrong? <Placemark>
   <name>NeKI - Budapest</name>
   <description><![CDATA[ NeKI Központ <br> Cím: 1012 Budapest, Márvány u. 1/d <br> GPS: N: 47,5002795601° E: 19,0298070271° <br> Tel.: +36 1 225 4400 ]]> </description>
   <style id="icon"></style>
   <Point>
    <coordinates>19.0298070271, 47.5002795601</coordinates>
   </Point>
  </Placemark>

Comment: Look in your KML file. What is the definition of the Style "icon" in the KML file? (FYI- that one doesn't exist, but style2 does)

Comment: I tryed with style2 but not working. Here is the KML link that u can download directly. Would u see inside please? https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?authuser=0&vps=3&ie=UTF8&msa=0&output=kml&msid=207719308852398276835.0004e7aadbef23d9a5c87

Comment: I don't know what i should do. Let's approaching the problem from the other side. If I directly upload the KML file to Google Maps all the pins are visible, but some polygons are missing: http://goo.gl/maps/53SUU The question what can i fix to visible the missing polygons?